# Regex help for matching multiple consecutive groups

Tags: python, regex

Stuck on this Regex problem for a bit now - I don't know if this is the correct way of expressing this problem but I would like to extract consecutively matching groups e.g for string "a->b->c" I would like to create matching groups for "a->b" & "b->c" and also the individual characters, so also "a", "b" and "c".  So far I have this Regex:

```
"(([A-Z a-z 0-9 _]+)(?:\s*->\s*)([A-Z a-z 0-9 _]+))"
```

which only successfully matches groups "a->b", "a" & "b" and not "b->c" & "c".

I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=((\w+)\s*->\s*(\w+)))
```

Try this with `re.findall`.See demo.The reason your regex was not working was because of overlapping matches.Once first match was done ,there was no element before `->` to match.To overcome this we use `lookahead` which does not capture but asserts

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/32

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?=((\w+)\s*->\s*(\w+)))')
test_str = "a->b->c"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```